# performance issues to consider from adding a cookie to 100K users?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I'm looking to track clicking on a site, mostly using jQuery to fire click events on anchors and buttons that add/update a cookie that I'll log into internal databases when a user hits an error page

This would mean adding some jQuery logic on the master page (that is on every page) that will get and update the cookie, along with hooking up jquery click events to most objects on the site.

the site sees roughly around 100K unique visitors a day and is heavy on database calls already

This is the first time I've incorporated anything like this into a site of this size. I'd like to know if any experts have concerns over doing something like this, what kind of performance overhead I can expect to cause with this solution, any ideas for implementation that would make this as non-noticeable as possible to the user and server loads, etc.

I appreciate any guidance anyone can give.

Comment: Are you adding a new cookie, using an existing one as-is, or adding extra info to an existing cookie?

Comment: Will the database only log things when a user hits an error page, or on all pages? How often _do_ users hit error pages? What "database" is the back-end?

Comment: The act of adding a cookie with client-side javascript/jQuery doesn't take any resources on your server other that the tiny amount of extra data that will be sent with future server requests.  Were you asking about something more than that?

Comment: @cdeszaq: adding a new cookie that doesn't already exist, the DB will only log when they hit the error page yes, until then it's all about cookie modification

Comment: @jfriend00 i guess my biggest concern is the pages loading slower for the client

Comment: Cookies don't cause pages to load slower unless your server takes longer to process the cookies that it sees in the client request.  That is up to your server.  If your server isn't doing anything with the cookies, then there is negligible impact (a hundred or so bytes of increased page size).

Comment: @jfriend00 - I disagree. I would be very leery of _anything_ that added more bytes than necessary to the request or response. RTT is a major source of page load slowness, and reducing the number of packets sent as much as possible is a primary way of speeding up a page load.

Comment: @cdeszaq - if you have ANY images on your page, then a few bytes of a cookie is completely irrelevant to the overall networking load.  Sure, minimize total bytes, but don't avoid using cookies just because of a few hundred bytes if they solve a useful problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 But a few bytes spread out over each and every request when loading a page adds up _really_ fast for the user, and across a 100k user site, that's a big impact. Yes, there are other ways to deal with that, but slowing down the user _at all_ is a poor choice when there are other ways to deal with it. There's a reason big sites focus on speed...it keeps users happy and more engaged.

Comment: @cdeszaq - I don't see how you can say 100 bytes added to a web page is a "big impact".  If you need the functionality of cookies, you will probably spend way more than 100 bytes trying to do solve the problem some other way.  It's not a big deal.  If you don't need cookies, then don't spend the 100 bytes and don't use cookies.  This is silly.  Google thinks about speed for it's homepage more than any other site I know of and I see 8 cookies on my copy of www.google.com.  Can you point to any large, high traffic site that doesn't use cookies for the reasons you describe?

Comment: @jfriend00 - For example, on this page (the page for this question), there are at least 20 requests. At an additional 100 bytes per request, that's an extra 2KB. Chrome tells me that this page transferred 65KB. Adding 2KB _more_ to that is a 3% size increase overall, and at least 2 more packets, since the average MTU is 1500 bytes. Even with a great RTT of 25ms, that's still at least an extra 50ms of load time _in the best case scenario_. Yahoo agrees: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cookie_size

Comment: @cdeszaq - point taken.  But, each packet is not an additional roundtrip.  More than one packet is in flight at a time based on TCP windowing algorithms.  I still ask you to find me a major site that chooses not to use cookies for this reason.  It's also a good reason to get your images off to another domain so the cookies aren't sent on every image request.  Cookies should be used when required, not used when not required.  Plus each separate networking request has it's own packets - they don't accumulate into a larger packet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To log something in cookies is not very good idea as the cookie have limitation of text length (4KB if i haven't forgotten). So if you would like to log some user activity you may try to use ajax to send request to the server and try to apply some logging system with high performance at the server side.

Comment: yes 4KB is the max, but i'm trying to avoid the notion of doing DB callbacks everytime I want to track this thing, the goal is to be very light weight. I've created the cookie in a way that it saves as much space as possible and don't anticipate the 4kb max to be a problem

Comment: The only bad things for cookie is that this 4KB will be transmitted to the server on every page request, it may produce big incoming traffic. You may use memcache at the serverside not to make a lot of db calls, if you want to store log temporary.

Comment: i'm afraid i haven't heard of 'memcache'ing serverside, sounds interesting i'll google it. my instinct question is, does this method mean i neeed to worry about server performance though?

Comment: what if i added a check for the length of the cookie, and if it was larger than whatever the max is (somewhere around 4kb) i would not try to do anything in my script. would this solve the notion of repeated max cookie size transmissions?

Answer (score 2):

The page load performance hit of adding a cookie to the request is going to depend on the current request size and the number of requests made to the domain with the new cookie for each page load. The cookie will get added to *each request* (including images, css, js, etc.) so depending on your scenario, it could be a large impact or a small one.

One way to combat the page load size issue is to have the static resources on a different cookieless domain that the domain that serves the pages. Requests to the cookieless domain will not include the new cookie and hence will not be affected by it. (Stack Overflow does exactly this).

As others have mentioned, however, using a cookie *may* not be the best way to track this, since it *does* have such a large impact on load time. Instead, I would suggest that you track this server-side by including the relevant information into the user's session. In addition to not increasing the client load time in any large way, you also have the advantage of being able to deal with a branching traffic pattern which is often seen when users open up multiple tabs off of a single page.

This does have a slight disadvantage in that you are taking on a slightly higher server-side load, but I would be *very* careful when it comes to increasing the client-side load time, since that is a *critical* metric for user happiness and engagement. A server-side load increase can be engineered around, especially for a 100k user site. A less-happy user due to a slower page load is *much* harder to fix.

Answer (score 0):

you could do some load testing.  [Visual Studio has a nice implementation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amit_chatterjee/archive/2009/01/29/web-and-load-testing-with-visual-studio-team-system.aspx)

No one else can tell you how well your hardware is going to handle this sort of thing, so load testing in a staging environment is generally your best option.  If your staging environment is similar enough, you should be able to load test it with a significantly smaller number of virtual users and see what sort of effects it will have on your servers.